# Updating database after a drag and drop operation

Tags: javascript, php

I want to update a database after a drop occurs, that drop operation gives me a variable which is an ID of a database row that i need to find and update. Is it possible to put php code in my javascript drop function so it makes a database query ? Or any other ideas how i can achieve this ? My function in javascript:

```
function drop(ev) 
{
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    //variable data is the variable that i need to find and update that specific row in my database
    var addthis = document.getElementById(data);
    var parent = document.getElementById(ev.target.id);
    parent.style.backgroundColor="#e9e9e9";
    var todelete = parent.firstChild;
    parent.appendChild(addthis);
    parent.removeChild(todelete);
}
```

Comment: You could perform an AJAX call to update the database with the relevant data.

Comment: which is the variable you want to save..?

Comment: @Sherin Jose its var data, 2nd line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to do this

First include a jquery plugin in your page like:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then edit your `drop()` as:

```
<script>
function update(){
    //your codes here

    //ajax for saving data
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'update.php',
        data:{data:data},
        success: function(){
            alert('Updated');
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Then you need to create a file **update.php** , in that file you can access the data variable as:

```
<?php
    $data   =   $_POST['data'];
    //save the $data as you wants
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an ajax call and post data you want.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to execute PHP code in Javascript.

What you'll need to do is make an ajax query to a php page. You can get more information about how to do that here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_xml.asp

And more info about XMLHttpRequest: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Ajax allright, never used it tho, any examples please ? I read the w3s tutorial but im still not sure how to get that variable, do i need to write new php file and then send that variable there with ajax ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you need to do.
And for an example, you have on the w3schools link, and plenty of others on Google